# What could be the reason SPICE is outputting very different CTR curve for this optocoupler?

Tags: opto-isolator, optoelectronics

For a [4N25/26](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf) I tried to plot the CTR vs LED Current graph by simulating the following circuit. To obtain results similar to the one in the datasheet I keep Vce constant at 10V and sweep the forward LED current between 0.1mA upto around 50mA.

[image]

As you see the peak CTR occurs when the LED current is around 1.8mA.

But in the datasheet [here](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf), at Fig. 2 or Fig. 3 the graph looks very different and the peak CTR occurs at 10mA LED current:

[image]

CTR plot is basically Ic/If when Vce is kept constant. But I obtain very different plot. Am I interpreting something wrong?

Comment: The saturated peak CTR occurs at 10 mA, not the unsaturated CTR (VCE = 10 volts).

Comment: This is a bit confusing to me. In the circuit I use the Vce is kept constant at 10V which means I'm plotting unsaturated CTR as you informed. But the LTspice plot doesn't look like that one either. If mine is unsaturated CTR, its shape must look like their unsaturated CTR.but it doesn't :(

Comment: Models don't have data sheets so I trust the real device (and its data sheet) more. Inspect the model is my advice.

Comment: Seems the transistor's gain is not modeled correctly. Simulation says it peaks at Ic = ~1.3mA, whereas the datasheet says it is fairly flat out to ~70mA and then drops off rapidly. I tested a real 4N25 and performance was similar to the datasheet.

Comment: Optocoupler technical data, particularly CTR, often suffers from a wide tolerance, so you may measure quite different values from one exemplar to another, especially when they are from different manufacturing batches.

Answer (score 2):

Spice models are often “you get what you pay for”, and many older devices have only rudimentary models - and ones that can mislead, too.

A modeling consultant would probably charge $5-$10k or something like that for an excellent model of this device. The price would represent the time spent doing the work. It’s for the most part quite tedious and takes custom hardware and model fitting software for best results.

Conversely, the makers of this device either messed up at some point in the management of the model library, or didn’t want to spend the money for a good model.

Comment: And to further expand on the point -- SPICE models are largely as-is and it's up to you, the end user, to determine whether they're accurate/representative enough for your particular application. That's not very useful when you want to predict what will happen in a novel circuit, but, it does show [the OP] is on the right track, testing their model!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the SPICE model was created for a particular version of the 4N25 that is manufactured by someone other than Vishay. Note that the results from your SPICE simulation do meet the datasheet specifications so in that sense the simulation is **correct**. The graphs that are provided in the datasheet are for informational purposes; the specified minimum CTR is 20% and that is the only guarantee you have.